# Java regex matches nothing

Tags: java, regex

```
String string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "<Request>\n" +
            "  <Item>\n" +
            "    <Type>C0401</Type>\n" +
            "    <InvDate>20150301</InvDate>\n" +
            "    <No>PK1000000</No>\n" +
            "  </Item>\n" +
            "  <Item>\n" +
            "    <Type>C0401</Type>\n" +
            "    <InvDate>20150301</InvDate>\n" +
            "    <No>PK1000002</No>\n" +
            "  </Item>\n" +
            "</Request>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<Item>)(.*)(</Item>)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    List<String> listMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(matcher.find())
    {
        listMatches.add(matcher.group(2));
    }
```

If I replace Item with `Type` or `InvDate` or `No`, I can get the content.

Looking for answer. Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML. Use proper XML parser.

Comment: I use dom4j, just trying to figure out how to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the option **Pattern.DOTALL** for multiline maches:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<Item>)(.*?)(</Item>)",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]**

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the option `Pattern.DOTALL` for multiline maches:

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<Item>)(.*)(</Item>)",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

But it is better to use a HTML-parser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DOTALL` flag to make `DOT` match any character including newlines also:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(<Item>)(.*)(</Item>)");
```

Or else:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(<Item>)(.*)(</Item>)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: ?s   
means what ?
and it gets weird result.

Comment: `(?s)` is for adding DOTALL flag which is same as my 2nd alternative above.